# Will several Soundcloud players on same page slow down my website?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, soundcloud

I'd like to swap out my current HTML5 audio player for the Soundcloud html5 widget player. My concern is that I have 11 posts per page on my Wordpress (org) music site, so that would be 11 different Soundcloud iframes per page. Will this slow my site down considerably?

Is there another way to embed the Soundcloud player besides iframe that would perform better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iframes will block onload and will slow down your page load.

[See this article for a breakdown of loading iframes, and asynchronous solutions](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance)

Alternatively you could load the iframe on demand, have a placeholder image that when clicked on uses javascript to load the soundcloud player.

[Here is a breakdown of this process applied to Youtube players](http://www.skipser.com/test/googlecode/gplus-youtubeembed/test.html)

Lastly you could use the SoundCloud api/library to create a lightweight player to embed in your posts.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I like the loading on demand idea, unfortunately this is out of my league so I'll try and find someone to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late but here's a way to do it without slowing down the page:

**Requirements:** jQuery and FitVids.js (this makes the iframe responsive without dealing with the css)

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function() {

$(".soundcloud-wrapper").each(function() {
        var URL = $(this).attr('id');
        var htm = '<iframe width="100%" height="200px" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + URL + '&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        $(this).html(htm).fitVids().removeClass('.loading');
  });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="soundcloud-wrapper" id="60229275"><!-- this loads the iframe without blocking --></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.soundcloud-wrapper iframe {
    /* --- your styles if applicable --- */
}

.soundcloud-wrapper.loading {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

Note: The .loading is a class that's removed when the iframe loads. I'm using it so that a height is there for Masonry layouts otherwise the space is collapsed. It is useful so that the page doesn't jump around even if you're not using Masonry, you'd change the value in both the CSS and the jQuery to reflect your iframe size.

Comment: Thanks Christina, I'll keep that method in mind if I decide to use it. I'm currently just lazy loading the Soundcloud players using jQuery Lazy Load XT and it works good. I have 10 players total on each page and only the first two on the screen load until you scroll down.